# How to fix PyQt6-tools installation error?

Tags: python, pip, pyqt, pyqt6

I want to create my small GUI app with PyQt6. I've installed PyQt6, but I also have to install PyQt6-tools. So, when I tried to get it, I got this error:

```
C:\Users\egorl>pip install pyqt6-tools
Collecting pyqt6-tools
  Using cached pyqt6_tools-6.1.0.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
  Using cached pyqt6_tools-6.0.3.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
  Using cached pyqt6_tools-6.0.2.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Collecting pyqt6==6.0.2
  Using cached PyQt6-6.0.2.tar.gz (940 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjhw74rau'
       cwd: C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yqby2el1\pyqt6_1bb69b3deb294f56858c9f93a5b67097
  Complete output (29 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 156, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
  AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 160, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4moc33ew\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\api.py", line 51, in build_wheel
      project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('pep517')
    File "C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4moc33ew\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\abstract_project.py", line 83, in bootstrap
      project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
    File "C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4moc33ew\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 587, in setup
      self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yqby2el1\pyqt6_1bb69b3deb294f56858c9f93a5b67097\project.py", line 60, in apply_user_defaults
      super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4moc33ew\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
      super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4moc33ew\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 234, in apply_user_defaults
      self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-4moc33ew\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\builder.py", line 67, in apply_user_defaults
      raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
  sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/80/2a/70619beeebc44e0d554beaed5c6687e55d8c284d8f0fa0eeb66372ce15d0/PyQt6-6.0.2.tar.gz#sha256=aab1b58e287cd8c91d7f7b8c4f91d68b8980f07fcd2ad6d9adbf0bb75347fb9a (from https://pypi.org/simple/pyqt6/) (requires-python:>=3.6.1). Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjhw74rau' Check the logs for full command output.
Collecting pyqt6-tools
  Using cached pyqt6_tools-6.0.1.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Collecting pyqt6==6.0.1
  Using cached PyQt6-6.0.1.tar.gz (940 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpmzbc3d1o'
       cwd: C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yqby2el1\pyqt6_271acbd829354c02a24c2e3326134647
  Complete output (29 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 156, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
  AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 160, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hk2owijm\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\api.py", line 51, in build_wheel
      project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('pep517')
    File "C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hk2owijm\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\abstract_project.py", line 83, in bootstrap
      project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
    File "C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hk2owijm\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 587, in setup
      self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yqby2el1\pyqt6_271acbd829354c02a24c2e3326134647\project.py", line 61, in apply_user_defaults
      super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hk2owijm\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
      super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hk2owijm\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 234, in apply_user_defaults
      self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-hk2owijm\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\builder.py", line 67, in apply_user_defaults
      raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
  sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f9/29/db2cb373ceac78c829def458fdfe72a637ed991d65f4e026997db5f3f200/PyQt6-6.0.1.tar.gz#sha256=313f0f4bf0158e7ce3b892f1ec16b3378e505e0f2458394c1245eb6807695c0d (from https://pypi.org/simple/pyqt6/) (requires-python:>=3.6.1). Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\egorl\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpmzbc3d1o' Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Cannot install pyqt6-tools==6.0.1.3.2, pyqt6-tools==6.0.2.3.2, pyqt6-tools==6.0.3.3.2 and pyqt6-tools==6.1.0.3.2 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    pyqt6-tools 6.1.0.3.2 depends on pyqt6-plugins<6.1.0.3 and >=6.1.0.2.2
    pyqt6-tools 6.0.3.3.2 depends on pyqt6-plugins<6.0.3.3 and >=6.0.3.2.2
    pyqt6-tools 6.0.2.3.2 depends on pyqt6==6.0.2
    pyqt6-tools 6.0.1.3.2 depends on pyqt6==6.0.1

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
```

I understand, that there is problem with dependencies, but I don't have any experiance in pip, so I don't know how to solve this problem. OS: Windows 10, python 3.10

Comment: use python3.9 instead

Answer (score 7):

Had the same errors with python 3.10, but didnt want to give up and revert to older version 3.9
Installed the designer seperately from https://build-system.fman.io/qt-designer-download
Its a small and quick install.

Comment: But this installs the Qt5 Designer, not the Qt6 designer. Is there asolution for Qt6? Update: I just realized that you can use puic6 to convert files created by Qt5 Designer

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by eyllanesc, using python3.9 worked out for me.

<PathToPython3.9>\python.exe -m pip install pyqt6_tools

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and after I checked the PyPi and pyqt6-tools GitHub repository, I found out the most recent compatible Python version is Python 3.9.
please switch your Python version to the 3.9 version and retry to install it using the pip install command in the terminal.

**<PathToPython3.9>\python.exe -m pip install pyqt6-tools**

I suggest you use a virtual environment to install the packages. it's worthy mentioning that the recent versions is not integrated with qt designer and you need to download it using the following link:

https://build-system.fman.io/qt-designer-download

Answer (score -1):

For those who use Linux (Ubuntu for me) and don't want to revert to Python 3.9 use this method:

1. Install flatpak if you don't have it `sudo apt install flatpak`
2. Add flatpak repo: `flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo`
3. Install Qt Designer: `flatpak install flathub io.qt.Designer`
4. AFter installation complete: run `designer` in terminal.

You can find more on: https://flathub.org/apps/details/io.qt.Designer